# Ruby scan for tag unless escaped by unescaped \

Tags: ruby, regex, escaping

Consider the string:

```
Hello <name>! I hear you like \<div> tags! Isn't that <adjective>?
```

I'd like to be able to scan the string for occurrences of `<(.*?)>`, for variable interpolation; but I don't want to be pick up escaped occurrences (like the `\<div>` above).

So far, so easy: using negative lookbehind I can do:

```
str.scan(/(?<!\\)<.*?>/)
# => ["<name>", "<adjective>"]
```

But I want to allow escaped `\` characters too:

```
# str is: 
# Hello <name>! Do you like escaping \\<thing>? I like \\\<lots> of escapes.
str.scan(re)
# Should give ["<name>", "<thing>"]
```

I can't work out how to do this. I thought of using a negative lookbehind to prevent an odd number of `\`, but Ruby doesn't support arbitrary length lookbehinds. I also thought of trying to consume an even number of `\` before the lookbehind checks for a single `\`, like so:

```
/(?:\\\\)*(?<!\\)<.*?>/
```

but it appears the lookbehind can still "see" the characters consumed by the previous group.

How can I match something, unless it has been preceded by an odd number of escaping characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*` guarantees an even number of backslashes.

Breakdown: `(?:\\\\)` matches exactly 2 backslashes. `*` makes it match 0, 2, 4, etc. `(?<!\\)` ensures the even number of backslashes we matched weren't preceded by another backslash (which would make the number odd).